# running a python program using argparse to setup input In Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I have a `.py` file following the normal code structure

```
def  main( args ): 
        .......
        .......

   if __name__ == "__main__":
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = “ forecasting example”)
      parser.add_argument("--train-window", default=2160, type=int)
      parser.add_argument("--test-window", default=336, type=int)
      parser.add_argument("--stride", default=168, type=int)
      parser.add_argument("-n", "--num-steps", default=501, type=int)
      parser.add_argument("-lr", "--learning-rate", default=0.05, type=float)
      parser.add_argument("--dct", action="store_true")
      parser.add_argument("--num-samples", default=100, type=int)
     parser.add_argument("--log-every", default=50, type=int)
     parser.add_argument("--seed", default=1234567890, type=int)
     args = parser.parse_args()
     main(args)
```

I was trying to run this program in Jupyter notebook, but it will get errors such as

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--train-window TRAIN_WINDOW]
                             [--test-window TEST_WINDOW] [--stride STRIDE]
                             [-n NUM_STEPS] [-lr LEARNING_RATE] [--dct]
                             [--num-samples NUM_SAMPLES]
                             [--log-every LOG_EVERY] [--seed SEED]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-4c744f03-3278-4aaf-af5e-50c96e9e41cd.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

my question is that, what are the right approaches or the modifications I need to make if I want to run a python program, which setup input parameters using argparse type of mechanism,  in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: What command caused the error you showed?

Comment: Using commandline arguments in a notebook is, at best, awkward.  The `sys.argv` the notebook sees comes from the kernel, with information on the interfacing javascript file.  Arguments provided when starting the server are for the server itself, not for any of the notebooks it might run.

Comment: The code seems to be incorrectly indented, anyway; `if __name__ == "__main__":` should be outside `def main():`

Comment: `-f C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-4c744f03-3278-4aaf-af5e-50c96e9e41cd.json` is from the server telling this kernel which `json` file to use.  Your `parser` can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be indented differently so you can `import` it into your notebook, or into another Python script. The whole point of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is that it gets executed immediately when Python parses the file; the condition is true only when you run the file directly, not when you `import` it. But the block needs to be indented differently, so that it's not inside any `def` or class or other block structure.

The way to use this from a notebook, then, is to call `main` (or whichever other functions from the imported code you want to run) with your desired parameters.

In this case, `main` has been designed to expect an `Argparse` object as its argument, which is quite unfortunate. A better design would simply do the argument parsing inside `main`, and expose a different function or set of functions for reuse as a library.

Assuming your `main` function's internals look something like

```py
def main(args):
    print(
        real_main(args.train_window, args.test_window,
                  stride=args.stride, num_steps=args.num_steps,
                  learning_rate=args.learning_rate,
                  dct=args.dct, num_samples=args.num_samples,
                  log_every=args.log_every, seed=args.seed))
```

and supposing you wanted to run the equivalent of

```sh
python thatfile.py -n 23 -lr 0.7--dct --num-samples 2300
```

the equivalent code in your notebook would look like

```py
from thatfile import real_main as that_main

print(that_main(2160, 336, num_steps=23,
                learning_rate=0.7, dct=True,
                num_samples=2300))
```

where the first two values are simply copied from the `argparse` defaults, and I obviously had to speculate a great deal about which parameters are required and which are optional keyword parameters, and whether they are named identically to the `argparse` field names.